# Where is glVertexAttribDivisor stored - VAO, VBO or global state?

Tags: c++, opengl

Here is a sample code :-

```
unsigned int instanceVBO;
glGenBuffers(1, &instanceVBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
...
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * 100,
       &translations[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); 
... ... ... 
glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceVBO);
glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);   
glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);   //<--- who own this setting?
//^ mostly copied from https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing
```

Who own the `glVertexAttribDivisor` setting? (VAO / instanceVBO / global state)

A comment in https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/99236/what-state-is-stored-in-an-opengl-vertex-array-object-vao-and-how-do-i-use-the#comment174555_99238  suggests that it is stored in VBO.

However, the comment contradicts (?) to the above code which calls `glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1)` ***after*** unbinds `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);`   .

I would be appreciate if you are also kind to provide reference that I can read more about :
which settings/states owned by which one of Opengl's thingy (VAO/VBO/etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vertex array divisor (`VERTEX BINDING DIVISOR`) is stored in the Vertex Array Objects state vector, separately for each vertex attribute (like enable state, offset, stride etc.).

The states which are stored in the VAO are listed in the specification in [Table 23.3: Vertex Array Object State](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=607&zoom=100,0,173).
VAOs are specified in [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification - 10.3.1 Vertex Array Objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=372&zoom=100,0,600).

See also [Vertex Specification - Instanced arrays](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)

Comment: How do you know?   I don't find such information in https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribDivisor.xhtml .   Oh... I see your edit.

Comment: @javaLover The states which are stored in the VAO are listed in the specification in [Table 23.3: Vertex Array Object State](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf#page=607&zoom=100,0,173).

Comment: I can't search & find `glVertexAttribDivisor` in that document.  In future, how can I find such great information (in the document) without you?

Comment: @javaLover  You've to search for `VertexAttribDivisor` (without  `gl`). Some good information is also provided on the [OpenGL wiki pages](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki), like [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). Of course the wiki is not the specification, it's just some additional explanation.